# how do i send react data to express backend?

Tags: reactjs, express

im building an app with express backend and react frontend but stack on hot to post data to my backnd.
this is my react frontend;

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      name: this.state.name
    };

    axios.post(`http://localhost:9000/testAPI`, { user })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Person Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is my backend script testAPI.JS;

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express.Router();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
});

module.exports=app;
```

this is the error message im getting;

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

any kind assistance will be apreciated

Comment: Are you exporting the app because you are using it as a serverless function? Is that the case you dont need to listen to a port

Comment: `express` helps you to create a server and serve client's requests whereas `axios` is used to make those requests to the server.

Comment: in your case, your server is making a request to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually make your express server listen

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/testAPI', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

And I am unsure what to do with the axios call in the backend

Comment: hi Julian.. i have tried to use that but i have got this error;

Comment: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Denoh\fy\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous>

Comment: Can you post code? Did you copy the example code I provided and extended it?